# 'undefined' data submited when using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm using HTML form to send data to google sheet, it work great. But when i add ajax code, the data send to google sheet always is "undefined", remove the code it'll work but it show the code really ugly after that, so i want using ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var submit = $("button[type='submit']");
  submit.click(function() {
    var data = $('form#test-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby8PCL7hef6N35QAEe7CcGWEVLeONJfy8ATXIsM5Sn7icTDMw8/exec',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'false') {
          alert('Oopps! Đã có lỗi. Quý khách hãy thử lại hoặc liên hệ trực tiếp qua hotline nhé.');
        } else {
          alert('Đã tiếp nhận thành công! Cát Tiên sẽ liên hệ lại trong thời gian sớm nhất. Cám ơn quý khách');
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby8PCL7hef6N35QAEe7CcGWEVLeONJfy8ATXIsM5Sn7icTDMw8/exec" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="SDT" id="ip2" placeholder=" SĐT hoặc Email">
  <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="button">Nhận</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

I don't know about code, all i using tutorial in web. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: jQuery **1.12.0**?!?  I'd consider upgrading

Comment: You might want to add `id="test-form"` in `<form>`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add an `ID` to your form. 
Your script is trying to serialize the form with the id `test-form` with this function:

```js
var data = $('form#test-form').serialize();
```

The form isn't found, because you forgot to add the id to the form.

Just replace your form's HTML with the following:

```html
<form 
id="test-form"
action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby8PCL7hef6N35QAEe7CcGWEVLeONJfy8ATXIsM5Sn7icTDMw8/exec" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="SDT" id="ip2" placeholder=" SĐT hoặc Email"> 
<button type="submit"id="submit-form" class="button">Nhận</button>
</form>
```